# Firestore Document Recall Working in One View Controller but Not Another

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Inside of a function I run this code to access a firestore database

```swift
      let db = Firestore.firestore()
```

```swift
      let docRef = self.db.collection("users").document(email)

      docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
          if let document = document, document.exists {
          let myDocument = document.data()
              let shareCode = myDocument?["shareCode"] as! String
```

In one view controller, this abstraction works with no issue, but when I run a very similar code, change being the field being recalled, the program can not find the document and skips past it. Is there any reason why this is happening.

In the working view controller I have:

```swift
import UIKit
import AVKit
import FirebaseFirestore
import Firebase
```

In the view controller with issues I have:

```swift
import UIKit
import AVKit
import FirebaseFirestore
import Firebase
import FirebaseStorage
```

Comment: *Is there any reason why this is happening* yes, there is. But there isn't enough info in the question to establish a cause. It could be a coding issue or perhaps a naming issue of the field in the database or something else entirely. Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Update your question with more info and we'll take a look.

Comment: Oh - and some additional code will really help; if there's an error in Firebase, you won't know about it or if the document doesn't exist your code will silently fail. Add an error handler and change this `if let document = document, document.exists` to notify you if the document doesn't exist.